# Xamarin forms aspect ratio in android

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've built my first Xamarin Forms App with a video control. The problem is that on the Android platform the aspect ratio is not kept but the video is filling the whole screen, both in horizontal and vertical mode.

I've tried all kind of solutions in the xaml code but can not get it to work. This is how I placed the control on my page:

```
<videoPlayer:VideoPlayer x:Name="Video1" AutoPlay="True" FillMode="ResizeAspect" WidthRequest="360" HeightRequest="202"></videoPlayer:VideoPlayer>
```

Maybe I need a custom render or something but since I'm new in the game I'm not sure to achieve this.

Grateful for help!

Peter

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing which `VideoPlayer` control you are using.

Comment: Supposedly [that one](https://github.com/adamfisher/Xamarin.Forms.VideoPlayer). `ResizeAspect` sounds correct. What's the parent of the player? Have you tried setting `VerticalOptions="Center"` manually?

Comment: <ContentPage.Content>
        <videoPlayer:VideoPlayer x:Name="Video1" AutoPlay="True" FillMode="ResizeAspect" WidthRequest="360" HeightRequest="202"></videoPlayer:VideoPlayer>
    </ContentPage.Content>

Comment: The namespace is xmlns:videoPlayer="clr-namespace:Octane.Xam.VideoPlayer;assembly=Octane.Xam.VideoPlayer"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Put the android videoPlayer inside of a stacklayout and then put them both inside of a frame. Cheers! FlatEarth!

```
<ContentPage.Content>

    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
        <On Platform="Android">
            <Frame BackgroundColor="Black">
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <o:VideoPlayer Source="{Binding imgUrl}" FillMode="ResizeAspectFill" AutoPlay="True"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </On>
        <On Platform="iOS">
            <o:VideoPlayer Source="{Binding imgUrl}" FillMode="ResizeAspect" AutoPlay="True"/>
        </On>

    </OnPlatform>
</ContentPage.Content>
```